# Python - Easiest way to get whole list object in a row

Tags: python, list

```
l = [['John'],['rides'],['bike'],['with'],['Mr.','Brown'],]
```

Assume that i have a list object like that. How can print my list objects in a row without using for statement and append to a string ?

**My desired output:**

```
print("my sentence:" + ? )
print("people:" + ? + ", " + ?)

my sentence: John rides bike with Mr. Brown
people: John, Mr. Brown
```

**MAJOR EDIT:**

The reason why i create this question is i analyze text based documentation and extract information with named entity so my problem is when i grouo sequential proper nouns which are "name + surname" or " Blah Blah Organization" in list like that :

```
[[u'Milletvekili', u'Ay\u015fe'], [u'oraya'], [u'Merve', u'Han\u0131m'], [u'ile'], [u'gitti'], [u'.']]
```

I have an algorithm which compare list objects with my datasets and describes the entity type. After the if statement decided [u'Milletvekili', u'Ay\u015fe'] is a person name ;

```
if gettype(arr[i][0].split("'")[0]) == "Özel İsim":
      newarr.append("[Person: " + str(arr[i][0]) + "]")
```

i append that in my new list which will be my in my output like [Person: Mr. Brown]. But i must group Capitalized words then i always have my output like that:

```
 [Person: [u'Milletvekili', u'Ay\u015fe']]
```

Answer (score 4):

Not quite elegant as the "sum", but alternatively you can use [`str.join()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.join) and [`map()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#map) with [`functools.partial()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functools.html#functools.partial):

```
>>> from functools import partial
>>> " ".join(map(partial(str.join, " "), l))
'John rides bike with Mr. Brown'
```

Comment: this also what im looking for but output is [Person: [u'Mr.', u'Brown']] any idea why i cant print objects in a row ?

Comment: @ArdaNalbant sorry, difficult to say. It is not clear what input data you've got at the moment and what is your desired output..could you edit the question and clarify? Thanks so much.

Comment: Edited my question and im afraid its not clear to understand i think but all i can say is i get [Person: [u'Mr.', u'Brown']] instead of [Person: Mr.Brown]

Answer (score 4):

Borrowing from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/952946/2285236):

```
" ".join(sum(l, []))
Out[130]: 'John rides bike with Mr. Brown'
```

Comment: very elegant solution!

Comment: exactly what i want but how can i implement this to my two print function ? I mean when i want to print john and brown i cant use sum in this way : print("people names:" + ",".join(sum(arr[0], arr[4])))

Comment: Also when i try that code above this is what i get for using unicoded list TypeError: can only concatenate list (not "unicode") to list

Comment: Can you give an example for the list that contains unicode characters?

Comment: Just edited the question instead of missunderstand anything

Comment: I'm afraid I don't understand the question. What exactly do you want to append to `newarr`? Is your example the desired output?

Answer (score 3):

Flatten the list, then join with `' '`.

```
>>> ' '.join(s for sub in l for s in sub)
'John rides bike with Mr. Brown'
```

Or with `itertools.chain`:

```
>>> from itertools import chain
>>> ' '.join(chain(*l))
'John rides bike with Mr. Brown'
```